# What were the official names of the "meaningful votes"?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, house-of-commons

I am trying to use the [Parliamentary Data API](http://explore.data.parliament.uk) to find out how MPs voted in the three meaningful votes thus far.

What were the official names of these motions/votes?

Comment: It appears that the term "meaningful vote" has become so wedded to Brexit that it now has its own [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meaningful_vote). Make of that what you will...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia article for "[Meaningful vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meaningful_vote)" goes into a lot of the background and further detail on this subject, but doesn't include the actual wording of the motions brought before the House of Commons. These can be obtained from the Commons' [Votes and Proceedings](https://www.parliament.uk/business/publications/business-papers/commons/votes-and-proceedings/).

The motions were as follows.

[Vote #1 - 15 January 2019](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201719/cmvote/190115v02.html):

> **Section 13(1)(b) of the European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018**
>
> That this House approves for the purposes of section 13(1)(b) of the European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018, the negotiated withdrawal agreement laid before the House on Monday 26 November 2018 with the title ‘Agreement on the withdrawal of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland from the European Union and the European Atomic Energy Community’ and the framework for the future relationship laid before the House on Monday 26 November 2018 with the title ‘Political Declaration setting out the framework for the future relationship between the European Union and the United Kingdom’.

[Vote #2 - 12 March 2019](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201719/cmvote/190312v02.html):

> **Section 13(1)(b) of the European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018**
>
> That this House approves for the purposes of section 13(1)(b) of the European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018 the following documents laid before the House on Monday 11 March 2019:
>
> (1) the negotiated withdrawal agreement titled ‘Agreement on the withdrawal of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland from the European Union and the European Atomic Energy Community’;
>
> (2) the framework for the future relationship titled ‘Political Declaration setting out the framework for the future relationship between the European Union and the United Kingdom’;
>
> (3) the legally binding joint instrument titled ‘Instrument relating to the Agreement on the withdrawal of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland from the European Union and the European Atomic Energy Community’, which reduces the risk the UK could be deliberately held in the Northern Ireland backstop indefinitely and commits the UK and the EU to work to replace the backstop with alternative arrangements by December 2020;
>
> (4) the unilateral declaration by the UK titled ‘Declaration by Her Majesty’s Government of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland concerning the Northern Ireland Protocol’, setting out the sovereign action the UK would take to provide assurance that the backstop would only be applied temporarily; and
>
> (5) the supplement to the framework for the future relationship titled ‘Joint Statement supplementing the Political Declaration setting out the framework for the future relationship between the European Union and the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland’, setting out commitments by the UK and the EU to expedite the negotiation and bringing into force of their future relationship.

[Vote #3 - 29 March 2019](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201719/cmvote/190329v01.html):

> **United Kingdom's withdrawal from the European Union**
>
> That this House
>
> notes the European Council Decision of 22 March 2019 taken in agreement with the United Kingdom extending the period under Article 50(3) of the Treaty on European Union, which provides for an extension to the Article 50 period to 22 May 2019 only if the House of Commons approves the Withdrawal Agreement by 29 March 2019;
>
> notes that if the House does not do so by that date the Article 50 period will only as a matter of law be extended to 12 April 2019 and that any extension beyond 22 May 2019 would require the UK to bring forward the necessary Day of Poll Order to hold elections to the European Parliament;
>
> notes that Article 184 of the Withdrawal Agreement refers to the Political Declaration between the UK and EU agreed on 25 November 2018, but that the EU has stated it remains open to negotiating changes to the Political Declaration;
>
> notes that the House is currently undertaking deliberations to identify whether there is a design for the future relationship that commands its support;
>
> notes that even should changes be sought to the Political Declaration, leaving the European Union with a deal still requires the Withdrawal Agreement;
>
> declares that it wishes to leave the EU with an agreement as soon as possible and does not wish to have a longer extension;
>
> therefore approves the Withdrawal Agreement, the Joint Instrument and the Unilateral Declaration laid before the House on 11 March 2019 so that the UK can leave the EU on 22 May 2019;
>
> notes that this approval does not by itself meet the requirements of section 13(1)(b) of the European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018;
>
> and resolves that it is content to proceed to the next steps of this process, including fulfilling section 13 of this Act.

(The third motion was published as a single block of text. I've broken it up here into separate paragraphs for ease of reading.)